# Что такое висячие указатели, в чем их опасность?

Tags: c++, c, указатели

Почему появляются проблемы подобного рода ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
char* f()
{
    char s[100];
    // страшное вычисление s
    return s;
}
```

Представили? вызываем `char * s = f();`. Нормально? вроде бы да.

Но когда мы начнем использовать этот указатель - тот `char s[100];` из функции давно может быть перезаписан чем-то другим (эта память выделяется в стеке только *на время работы функции*). И мы получаем **висячий** указатель - т.е. он есть и даже куда-то указывает... Только там может быть что угодно.

Или -

```
s = malloc(...);
....
free(s);
```

Значение `s` остается - `free` его не меняет, но указывает оно на память, которая освобождена, может быть выделена заново, перезаписана... или, например, еще раз удалена.

Так понятнее?

Comment: Ещё можно упомянуть "double free"

Comment: @vp_arth Ну, это все же следствие "висячести", а не причина :) Но вы, конечно, правы. Сейчас дополню.